# Making GridBagLayout more compact

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I am trying to accomplish the following with GridBagLayout:

The frame will receive a collection of "fields" (JLabel, JTextField pairs), I want to arrange them in a 'Grid-like' fashion where a row will contain 2 such pairs (JLabel1 JField1 JLabel2 JField2). When a row has these four components, the next components are added to another row.

**EDIT**: I would like the components to start at the top of the panel

My code produces the following layout. I would like the components to be laid out more compactly (especially the vertical distance)

[image: pic]

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class Test extends JFrame{

private JPanel _panel;

public Test() {
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setResizable(true);
    this.setVisible(true);
    Dimension size = new Dimension(600,600);
    this.setMinimumSize(size);
    this.setSize(size);
    this.setPreferredSize(size);
    _panel = new JPanel();
    this.add(_panel);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t = new Test();
    String[] labels = {"label1", "label2","label3","label4","label5"};
    String[] fieldValues = {"value1","value2","value3","value4","value5"};
    t.createFields(labels,fieldValues);
}

private void createFields(String[] labels, String[] fieldValues) {
    _panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    int col = 0;
    int row = -1;
    for(int i=0; i < labels.length;i++) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(labels[i] + ":", JLabel.TRAILING);
        JTextField field = new JTextField(fieldValues[i]);
        Dimension size = new Dimension(200,30);
        field.setPreferredSize(size);
        label.setLabelFor(field);


        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.ipadx = 0;
        c.ipady = 0;
        c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        c.gridx = col%4;
        if(i%2 == 0) row++;
        c.gridy = row;
        _panel.add(label,c);

        col++;
        c.gridx = col%4;
        _panel.add(field,c);
        col++;
    }

    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Swing is honoring your setPerferredSize of 600,600.

Comment: If you did not want your rows to get extra vertical space, then why did you set weighty = 1?

Comment: @Shoikana I would like the Frame to be that size. I want the components to compactly fill that area in starting from the top left corner of the panel

Comment: @Ordous had the problem that if I set weighty = 0 then everything clumps in the center

Comment: @SimonRubin As I pointed out in comments to the answer, that is easily rectified by adding an invisible placeholder component to take on remaining space. It should now be in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind your elements being in center of panel (vertically and horizontally), then remove

```
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.weightx = 1;
```

from your code.
If center is wrong place, add

```
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx=4;
    c.gridy=labels.length;
    c.weightx=1;
    c.weighty=1;
    _panel.add(new JLabel(),c);
```

after your loop

Comment: Don't want them to clump in the center!

Comment: And if you do mind, add an empty panel with weighty = 1, weightx = 1 on the bottom right...

Comment: Nice suggestion, answer edited to provide an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your GUI to be that size, but have the components in a compact size, then place them in their own JPanel, one that uses GridBagLayout, and then add that JPanel to your main GUI JPanel. If you want the components to fill the width, then have the main JPanel use BorderLayout, and add your GBL using JPanel BorderLayout.NORTH or .SOUTH whatever your need is.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GridBagExample extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 600;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;

   public GridBagExample() {
      super(new BorderLayout());
      add(new GridBagUsingPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagExample");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new GridBagExample());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class GridBagUsingPanel extends JPanel {
   public static final int COLUMNS = 2;
   public static final int ROWS = 3;
   private static final int TF_COLS = 10;
   private static int inset = 5;
   private static final Insets INSETS = new Insets(inset, inset, inset, inset);
   private static final Insets EXTRA_INSETS = new Insets(inset, inset, inset, 8 * inset);
   private static final int EB_GAP = 10;

   public GridBagUsingPanel() {
      super(new GridBagLayout());
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(EB_GAP, EB_GAP, EB_GAP, EB_GAP));
      for (int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++) {
         for (int c = 0; c < COLUMNS; c++) {
            addComponent(r, c);
         }
      }
   }

   private void addComponent(int r, int c) {
      int count = 1 + r * COLUMNS + c;
      JLabel label = new JLabel("label " + count);
      JTextField textField = new JTextField("value " + count, TF_COLS);

      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridx = 2 * c;
      gbc.gridy = r;
      gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
      gbc.gridwidth = 1;
      gbc.gridheight = 1;
      gbc.insets = INSETS;
      gbc.weightx = 0.1;
      gbc.weighty = 1.0;
      add(label, gbc);

      gbc.gridx++;
      gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      gbc.weightx = 1.0;
      if (c != COLUMNS - 1) {
         gbc.insets = EXTRA_INSETS;
      }
      add(textField, gbc);
   }

}
```